# SSRS Report to show the monthly cash flow of current Lease

Tags: reporting-services

I am working on SSRS report and want to use that to show the monthly cash flow of current lease. Expected result as attached screenshot.

How can SSRS report can do like that ?
Anyone can have suggestion ?
Thanks a lot !!

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at Matrix layout? Column A through to E would be outside the column group and the rest would be inside.. looks pretty straight forward.. provided you have your Datasource sorted

Comment: Thanks Harry. The flow should be that user input the Lease No and the SSRS report should breakdown the cash flow by monthly likes attached screenshot. So now I am stuck on how SSRS report can check the month which is whether has rental income or rent free.

Comment: well.. how do you get the data? Is it a SQL server back end? I'm sure there is a logic to all of this.. Some tables that hang together that you can query etc.. all you have provided is a sample screenshot and input parameter.. nothing else!

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I am using Oracle 12c and developing SSRS report by using PLSQL. Two technical difficulties that I am facing are how to check the date is falling into Rent Free period and SSRS report column can expand monthly and automatically (Jan-18, Feb-18 and Mar-18, etc).

Comment: show what your dataset looks like please

Comment: It has fields LeaseNo, LeaseStartDate and LeaseEndDate in Lease table, 
and LeaseNo, ReviewDate and ReviewType in Rent History table.

Attached screenshot as example,

Lease table
LeaseNo = 12345
LeaseStartDate = 01-Jan-2018
LeaseEndDate = 13-Dec-2020

Rent History table
LeaseNo = 12345
ReviewType = Rent
ReviewDate = 01-Jan-2018
Amount = 10,000
ReviewType = Rent Free
ReviewDate = 01-Mar-2018
Amount = 0
ReviewType = Rent Free
ReviewDate = 01-Apr-2018
Amount = 0
ReviewType = Rent 
ReviewDate = 16-Apr-2018
Amount = 10,000